# Eclipse perspective won't stop changing

Tags: eclipse, debugging, pydev, perspective

Every time reopen my Eclipse, the menubar loses all of the Debug actions. I believed I have made my desired perspective the default one, but somehow the perspective itself loses the Debug Action Set. I can always edit the perspective to include the action set, but I want to make it so I'll always have the Debug action set included without manually adding it all the time. How can I do this?

I don't if this is related but also when my program stops at a breakpoint, get this pop-up error `'Perspective Switch Job' has encountered a problem.` And the details say `java.lang.NullPointerException` even though I'm not using java in this project.

I'm using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Mars Release 4.5.0, I am also using PyDev 4.2.0.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2015-12-16 13:51:34.602
!MESSAGE Error
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyShowView(WorkbenchPage.java:1270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$12.run(WorkbenchPage.java:4211)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView(WorkbenchPage.java:4207)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.views.ViewContextService.showViewQuiet(ViewContextService.java:1175)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.PerspectiveManager$4.runInUIThread(PerspectiveManager.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.PerspectiveManager$MyUIJob$1.run(PerspectiveManager.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4155)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3772)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message

Comment: There's a large backtrace of java files, not sure if they help since I'm not using java,

Comment: Eclipse is written in Java so you are seeing the report of the problem.

Comment: I see, here's the log entry http://pastebin.com/TXXnvhJx

Comment: Looks like this is probably Eclipse bug [471782](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471782) due to be fixed in 4.5.2

Comment: So this Perspective Switch Job issue is actually related to the Eclipse perspective change problem?